# How to define an interface with keys restricted to a union of values of a property contained in each object in an array of such objects?

Tags: typescript

```
interface Filter {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

type Filters = Filter[];

const filters = [{ id: 'f1', name: 'f1name'}, { id: 'f2', name: 'f2name'}]

interface State { ... }

const state = {
    f1: any,
    f2: any
}
```

I would like to type `state`. I want to have a `State` type that is an object that has the same number of properties as the objects in `filters`, and I want to restrict the type of each property to the union of the types of the `id` property from `filters`.

In the example above, state is of type `State` and that is "an object with keys `'f1' | 'f2'` that have value `any`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare the filters with `as const` to preserve the string literal types, you can do this:

```
const filters = [{ id: 'f1', name: 'f1name' }, { id: 'f2', name: 'f2name' }] as const

type Id = (typeof filters)[number]['id']
type State = Record<Id, any>

const state: State = {
    f1: 42,
    f2: 'any'
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLADaSsg3gWAChkTlgATALmQGcwpQBzAbiNORDgFsJq6GQLIgF8iRMAE8ADinRZoNZAF40mbAG0Auq0JEEAexB1kMNQuXJ1uMlWQByGAEY7AGg7de9p5x53kwt2sKagcAJld3HhCYUJ8IP2FNZDhFAyMwMUJJGWQASXILAApsiH0YEzMoGgBKdRAAVy4AI2hNdTsKO01xaRQAZTA4SAsAJQgDKHIAHny3OBAJAD5MtOM6Ic8BjYsCYlInagAWUJc2fdCQ+Yk7ESA)

Comment: I was trying to answer the question but I missed the idea of using the `number` keys of the array, that's brilliant, +1.